# Convert output of shell script to .csv

Tags: command-line, scripts, text-processing, csv

I want to convert the output of the below patchhistory.sh shell script to csv, so that I can get the information in column format like this:

```
servername              patch history                            uptime
1.test-tch008.test.com  rsyslog Mon 16 Jul 2018 04:36:50 AM EDT  02:18:20 up 953 days,  8:16,  1 user,  load average: 0.08, 0.06, 0.08
```

```
[root@test-ops002 tmp]# ./patchhistory.sh

test-tch008.test.com
rsyslog                                  Mon 16 Jul 2018 04:36:50 AM EDT
 02:18:20 up 953 days,  8:16,  1 user,  load average: 0.08, 0.06, 0.08
Connection to test-tch008 closed.
test-twh005.test.com
rsyslog                                  Mon 16 Jul 2018 04:37:08 AM EDT
 02:18:21 up 1750 days, 13:38,  1 user,  load average: 0.07, 0.14, 0.17
Connection to test-twh005 closed.
test-vch108.test.com
rsyslog                                  Mon 16 Jul 2018 04:38:55 AM EDT
 02:18:23 up 94 days,  1:33,  1 user,  load average: 0.30, 0.28, 0.27
Connection to test-vch108 closed.
test-vch109.test.com
rsyslog                                  Mon 16 Jul 2018 04:39:03 AM EDT
 02:18:25 up 31 days,  1:22,  1 user,  load average: 0.18, 0.10, 0.08
Connection to test-vch109 closed.
test-vch110.test.com
rsyslog                                  Mon 16 Jul 2018 04:39:58 AM EDT
 02:18:26 up 31 days,  1:03,  1 user,  load average: 0.14, 0.21, 0.09
Connection to test-vch110 closed.
test-vwh114.test.com
rsyslog                                  Mon 16 Jul 2018 04:45:18 AM EDT
 02:18:28 up 84 days,  5:06,  1 user,  load average: 0.22, 0.19, 0.12
Connection to test-vwh114 closed.
test-vwh115.test.com
rsyslog                                  Mon 16 Jul 2018 04:46:10 AM EDT
 02:18:30 up 12 days,  4:27,  1 user,  load average: 0.13, 0.16, 0.11
Connection to test-vwh115 closed.
test-vwh116.test.com
rsyslog                                  Mon 16 Jul 2018 04:46:17 AM EDT
 02:18:32 up 84 days,  6:09,  1 user,  load average: 0.10, 0.16, 0.23
Connection to test-vwh116 closed.
test-vwh117.test.com
rsyslog                                  Mon 16 Jul 2018 04:46:26 AM EDT
 02:18:33 up 29 days, 14:31,  2 users,  load average: 0.32, 0.19, 0.19
Connection to test-vwh117 closed.
test-vxh104.test.com
rsyslog                                  Mon 16 Jul 2018 04:49:11 AM EDT
 02:18:35 up 953 days,  9:02,  2 users,  load average: 0.06, 0.03, 0.00
Connection to test-vxh104 closed.
```

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: `perl` is the tool I'd suggest for this. What have you tried?

Comment: Best would be to do that from within the script itself instead of parsing its output, and that depends on what you're doing in the script itself and which commands are used.  90% of the time shell script probably could be better converted into `awk` or `perl` script entirely.

Comment: Close voters this question is very clear. It has an input sample and example of desired output. Sure, the title is not descriptive (idk how to fix it) but that's no excuse. It's also definitely not off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Well, looks like we can do it with `sed` :)

This looks OK to me (the leading `|` is me assuming you'll be piping the output of your script into the command):

```
| sed -r '/test/ N;N;N; s/(.*)\n([A-Za-z]*)\s*(.*)\n(.*)\n.*/\1  \2 \3  \4/'
test-tch008.test.com  rsyslog Mon 16 Jul 2018 04:36:50 AM EDT   02:18:20 up 953 days,  8:16,  1 user,  load average: 0.08, 0.06, 0.08
test-twh005.test.com  rsyslog Mon 16 Jul 2018 04:37:08 AM EDT   02:18:21 up 1750 days, 13:38,  1 user,  load average: 0.07, 0.14, 0.17
test-vch108.test.com  rsyslog Mon 16 Jul 2018 04:38:55 AM EDT   02:18:23 up 94 days,  1:33,  1 user,  load average: 0.30, 0.28, 0.27
test-vch109.test.com  rsyslog Mon 16 Jul 2018 04:39:03 AM EDT   02:18:25 up 31 days,  1:22,  1 user,  load average: 0.18, 0.10, 0.08
```

But if you want to put that header line in... well I can only think of this ugly way...

```
| sed -r '1 s/^/servername            patch history                             uptime\n/; /test/ N;N;N; s/(.*)\n([A-Za-z]*)\s*(.*)\n(.*)\n.*/\1  \2 \3  \4/'
servername            patch history                             uptime
test-tch008.test.com  rsyslog Mon 16 Jul 2018 04:36:50 AM EDT   02:18:20 up 953 days,  8:16,  1 user,  load average: 0.08, 0.06, 0.08
test-twh005.test.com  rsyslog Mon 16 Jul 2018 04:37:08 AM EDT   02:18:21 up 1750 days, 13:38,  1 user,  load average: 0.07, 0.14, 0.17
test-vch108.test.com  rsyslog Mon 16 Jul 2018 04:38:55 AM EDT   02:18:23 up 94 days,  1:33,  1 user,  load average: 0.30, 0.28, 0.27
test-vch109.test.com  rsyslog Mon 16 Jul 2018 04:39:03 AM EDT   02:18:25 up 31 days,  1:22,  1 user,  load average: 0.18, 0.10, 0.08
```

#### Explanation

- `-r` Use extended regex - saves a few backslashes
- `s/old/new/` replace `old` with `new`
- `1 s/^/literally what I want to insert\n/` replace the start of the first line with your header line, ending with a new line. Luckily, `sed` interprets `\n` as a newline in this context.
- `/test/` find a line with `test`
- `N;N;N` read the next three lines in too, so we can use `\n` in the regex and process all three lines
- `(.*)` save any number of any characters (save the whole line)
- `([A-Za-z])` save a bunch of letters (this is `rsyslog`, so you could just write `rsyslog` if it's always the same).
- `\s` horizontal whitespace
- `\1  \2 \3  \4` The saved patterns, with the correct spacing.

Comment: Great answer, lots of explanations.